# NSURLSessionDataTask memory warning app crash

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsurlrequest, nsurlsessiondownloadtask, nsurlsessiondatatask

I'm using **NSURLSessionDataTask** to download a file of size > 1 GB. But I always get memory warning during downloading and eventually my app crashes. I did look into the Apple documentation of **NSURLSessionDataTask** and it did say that the Data is loaded into the memory.

My question is whether I can set some sort of **cachePolicy** of **NSURLMutuableRequest** so that the Data is **not loaded into the memory**.

**NOTE**: I'm not using **downloadTaskWithRequest** for downloading because I had some issues regarding **resuming the download** if the **resumeData** returned by **cancelByProducingResumeData** method returned **nil**. That's why using **range requests** I used **dataTaskWithRequest** to download the file.

Thanks

Comment: Please add some code to illustrate what you've tried so far and help others diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

No.  NSURLSessionDataTask returns the contents as an NSData object, which by definition is always in RAM.